# Update value of array field inside JSON string

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have column content in my database that is a type of STRING with JSON structure:

```
{
    "id": "12",
    "Name": "Ana",
    "lastName": "Johnes",
    "data": [{
            "id": "2",
            "value": "mr"
        }, {
            "id": "3",
            "value": "Ana"
        }
    ]
   
}
```

Schema of myTable:
`Content (STRING)`

I want to hash and update the 'value' inside the data. I tried using REPLACE function like this but it didn't replace the array "data" with hashed "value":

```
UPDATE `myTable` set content=
  REPLACE(content, ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(
      SELECT
        data
      FROM
        UNNEST(json_extract_array(content,
            "$.data"))AS data), ","),ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(
      SELECT
        REPLACE(data, "\""||json_value(data,
            "$.value")|| "\"", '"'||`hashField`(json_extract_scalar(data,
              '$.value'))||'"' )
      FROM
        UNNEST(json_extract_array(content,
            "$.data")) AS data), ","))
WHERE true
```

Expected output in column content should look like this:

```
{
    "id": "12",
    "Name": "Ana",
    "lastName": "Johnes",
    "data": [{
            "id": "2",
            "value": "1256f52fe6125"
        }, {
            "id": "3",
            "value": "6712gf7e1fe76"
        }
    ]
   
}
```

Comment: please clarify - what is expected output - just provide sample output based on already presented input data

Comment: expected output would be like this:`{
    "id": "12",
    "Name": "Ana",
    "lastName": "Johnes",
    "data": [{
            "id": "2",
            "value": "25623g7263d672gd"
        }, {
            "id": "3",
            "value": "67fwevtwe76d7t",
        }
    ]
   
}`

Comment: please update your question with this! and where "25623g7263d672gd" and "67fwevtwe76d7t"  come from?

Comment: that is the result of hash function, my question is how can I update these fields that depend on value of 'value' field

Comment: The hash function can be SHA1(input), it doesn't really matter, what is important is that I update 'value'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider query below:

```sql
with sample_data as (

  select '{"id": "12","Name": "Ana","lastName": "Johnes","data": [{"id": "2","value": "mr"}, {"id": "3","value": "Ana" }] }' as json_string
),

hash_value as (
select 
  struct(
    json_extract_scalar(json_string,'$.id') as id,
    json_extract_scalar(json_string,'$.Name') as Name,
    json_extract_scalar(json_string,'$.lastName') as lastName,
    array(
        select as struct
          json_extract_scalar(arr_data, '$.id') as id,
          sha1(json_extract_scalar(arr_data, '$.value')) as value 
        from unnest(json_query_array(json_string,'$.data')) as arr_data) as data
        ) as json_struct

from sample_data
)

select 
  to_json_string(json_struct) as json_string 
from hash_value
```

Output:

[image]

---

**UPDATE (Add UPDATE statement)**

NOTE: `UPDATE` needs a **WHERE statement** to determine what data point to update. Since you did not present any unique column, I added a column **id** so I can use this a reference for the `UPDATE` statement.

```sql
update `your-project.your_dataset.your_table`
set json_string = new_json_string
from (
with hash_value as (
select 
  struct(
    json_extract_scalar(json_string,'$.id') as id,
    json_extract_scalar(json_string,'$.Name') as Name,
    json_extract_scalar(json_string,'$.lastName') as lastName,
    array(
        select as struct
          json_extract_scalar(arr_data, '$.id') as id,
          sha1(json_extract_scalar(arr_data, '$.value')) as value 
        from unnest(json_query_array(json_string,'$.data')) as arr_data) as data
        ) as json_struct

from `your-project.your_dataset.your_table`
)

select 
  to_json_string(json_struct) as new_json_string 
from hash_value
)
where id = 111
```

Comment: Excellent and I think it would be better if you use **Standard JSON extraction functions** instead of legacy ones.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#standard_json_extraction_functions_recommended

Comment: @Jaytiger Oh I see. Thanks for the suggestion. Will definitely apply this on my queries.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The result should definitely look like this, but is there a way to use UPDATE on this table so I can change the value of this field?

Comment: @mini_batman I updated my answer to add the UPDATE statement

Answer (score 0):

> The hash function can be SHA1(input), it doesn't really matter, what is important is that I update 'value'

Based on above statement, I assume you just really want to mask real values, the replacement value really do not matter - if so consider below naïve and super simple approach

```
select regexp_replace(Content, r'"value":\s*"([^"]+)"', '"value": "XXX')
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output (of that column) is

[image]

And if you need to update that field in the table - you can simply use

```
update your_table
set Content = regexp_replace(Content, r'"value":\s*"([^"]+)"', '"value": "XXX')
where true
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I would still like to have hash depending on the value. This will replace every value with the same hashing value.